# Set base to object of undetermined size

Tags: python, c++, c++11, memory-management, base-class

I would like to recently describe the situation I'm faced with, in order to give the question some context.

I'm writing a Python C++ wrapper. Python's basic unit is PyObject. Every entity in Python is a PyObject *+ more optional stuff*.

That is to say the first `sizeofPyObject)` bytes are guaranteed to fill out the fields of a PyObject, but various objects may allocate additional contiguous memory.

The benefit (reason?) for this is that anything can be typecast back into a meaningful `PyObject`.

I'm attempting to wrap such a beast:

```
class CxxWrapper : PyObject {}
```

Say I create a `void foo(PyObject* p)`, and insert `foo` into one of the Python runtime's function-pointer tables.

Then the runtime will trigger this function (for whatever reason) passing a pointer to the relevant `PyObject`.

I would like to be able to typecast this straight back to its corresponding CxxWrapper object:

```
CxxWrapper* cxxw = static_cast<CxxWrapper>p;
```

However, I can't see any way to get this mechanism to work. Because I can't see any way to set the base object to some `PyObjectPlusExtra`.

Is there any way to do this? And if not, what is the C++ limitation being hit?

Comment: you definitely can declare some classes of which the base class or the first member is a PyObject, and then any other members follow.

Comment: `CxxWrapper* cxxw = static_cast<CxxWrapper*>(p);`

Comment: @JonathanPotter, but then CxxWrapper's own constructor doesn't get a chance to construct the derived object.

Comment: `cxxw` is a pointer, it doesn't have a constructor.

Comment: My bad, I should have explained that CxxWrapper is actually a full C++ class with it's own data. Calling it 'wrapper' was misleading, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A badly formed question. With 20:20 hindsight, here's what's going on:

I'm dealing with a C Library uses a C-style inheritance scheme, i.e.

```
struct CBase{
    int a,b;
}

struct CDer{
    CBase ab;
    int c;
}
```

I'm planning my C++ code thus:

```
class CxxBase : CBase
```

So if I get a pointer from C, I can typecast to the equivalent CxxBase object and vice versa.

Problem is that C++ manages inheritance pretty much the same as that C example.  Final:Der:Base will store a Base then a Der then a Final object in contiguous memory.

So it's impossible to perform this union. Both CDer and CxxDer will be of unknown size.

A different technique is needed, such as the mapping propose by Barry.

However, that involves a reasonably expensive lookup.

I can see no solution better than the existing one in the project I'm working on:

```
struct Bridge {
    CObj cob;
    CxxObj* p_cxxob;
}

const CxxObj& to_cxx(CObj* cob) { return *(cob->p_cxxob); }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the wrong way to do it, since you won't be able to construct your object ever! What you can do instead is define a map between the `PyObject`s and your objects:

```
std::unordered_map<PyObject*, CxxStff> stuff;

void foo(PyObject* o) {
    CxxStuff& extra = stuff[o];
    // etc
}
```

Put whatever you want in that extra class and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Didn't see the c++11 tag.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't considered this approach. It looks rather costly, although I don't know what the cost of typecasting base->derived is.

Comment: The cost of the cast is zero, but it doesn't really matter since you'd never have a derived object.